# Updating a local state and a shared state in one stroke

Tags: reactjs, flux

Consider a component in React which has its own state and also uses some shared state (shared states are stored within a Store).

Here's a sample component for better understanding the question:

```
var ControllerView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {privateState: 1, sharedState: -1};
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    Store.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    Store.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange: function() {
    this.setState({
      privateState: this.state.privateState,
      sharedState: Store.getSharedState()
    });
  }

  stepForward: function() {
    this.setState({
      privateState: this.state.privateState + 1,
      sharedState: this.state.sharedState
    });
    Action.decrease();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.stepForward}>Go forth with private and shared state</button>
        <div>Private State: {this.state.privateState}</div>
        <div>Shared State: {this.state.sharedState}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

As you can see in the given code, there's a button which pressing it will result in changing both private state and shared state. A private state can simply be updated by calling the `setState` method. But following the Flux architecture, updating a store should go through `actions`. That's why there's a `Action.decrease();`.

Just a recap of what will happen when an action is called;

1. The action method called will come up with the new data (either through calculation or calling a service, in my question it doesn't matter how you come up with the new data).
2. Once the action has got the new data, it will dispatch it so any store interested in it and they will pick it up and store it.
3. After any store saves the data, it will emit a change notifying any component registered within that store to pick up the new data. This is when the component's `_onChange` is called.

So when the button is pressed, the component's state will update twice, once to update the private state and the second time when `_onChange` is called to update the shared state. These two `setState` calls happen one after the other in one thread.

What I experienced is that in such cases only the last `setState` will apply and the previous ones are discarded. My question is how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When calling setState, you should only include the properties you are actually updating - other properties in the state will be left alone. You are seeing the fact that, when setState is called, this.state is not immediately updated, but only once the actual react render starts (immediately after componentWillUpdate() and before render() I think). So when you call your second setState, you are replacing the new value for privateState with the old one (which is still held in this.state until the render happens). So, your code should look like:

```
_onChange: function() {
  this.setState({
    sharedState: Store.getSharedState()
  });
}

stepForward: function() {
  this.setState({
    privateState: this.state.privateState + 1,
  });
  Action.decrease();
}
```